# Which of the followings have a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the following sets :

$$S=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\right\}.$$

$$D=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\right\}.$$

$$E=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:2x^2+3y^2\le 1\right\}.$$

Which of the following are correct ?

(a) If $f:D\to S$ is continuous then $f$ has a fixed point.

(b) $f:S\to S$ is continuous then $f$ has a fixed point.

(c) If $f:E\to E$ is continuous then $f$ has a fixed point.

We know from Brouwer's fixed point theorem , " A continuous mapping of a closed & convex set into itself necessarily has a fixed point. "

From this theorem we have , option (c) is correct & option (b) is wrong.

But what about options (a) ?

Are there any theorem for a continuous function from one set to another set have to a fixed point?

Comment: for a) note that $S\subset D$ and $D$ is closed and convex

Comment: So what? It is NOT clear to me...Please explain....

Comment: Is it more clear in my answer?

Comment: Here are more fixed points theorems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem#List_of_fixed_point_theorems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) note that $S\subset D$ and $D$ is closed and convex. So $f(D)\subset S\subset D$ and you can apply the Theorem.

b) depends on the function, e.g. $f(x)=x$ or $f$ is a rotation around the origin.

c) you are right.

Comment: In statement of Brouwer's fixed point theorem the condition is necessary..So why I am wrong in (b)?

Comment: @Panja.S. no the condition is sufficient but not necessary for the existence of a fixed point.

Comment: Ohh...So (a) is also TRUE ?

Comment: @Panja.S. yes :)

Comment: I have a last question..Are there any necessary or sufficient condition for a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ to have a fixed point? where $X$ & $Y$ are any arbitrary two spaces, not necessarily $Y\subset X$

Comment: @Panja.S. not to my knowledge (unfortunately).

Comment: Ok.......@ Surb

Comment: For your answer in (b) , $f$ is from unit circle(subset of $\mathbb R^2$) to itself..So how you take $f(x)=x$ ?

Comment: @Panja.S. Well set $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in S$.

Comment: How we can say that $f$ has no fixed point?

Comment: @Panja.S. When $f$ is the identity function, then every point is a fixed point. If $f$ is a rotation around the origin (different from the identity), then $f$ has no fixed point.

Comment: Give example such that $f$ has no fixed point

Comment: @Panja.S. do you read what I write?

Comment: I really don't understand your answer..If $f$ is a rotation about origin then what is the form of $f$ ?

Comment: @Panja.S. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions Note also that it is known that every rotation of the plane have exactly one fixed point. Here it is $(0,0)$ and $(0,0)\notin S$.

Comment: Ohh..Yes..I understood the rotation & I construct a function using rotation & I show that the function has a fixed point $(0,0)$ but I could not find this fact that $(0,0)\notin S$. So I thought that your rotation sense is one another..Now it is clear to me.. & we may delete some comments now...